# How to deploy multiple web apps in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I have two web jsp+servlet  applications which i have deployed in tomcat server. I access both apps using below urls

```
http://www.example.com:8100/admin 
http://www.example.com:8100/client
```

I dont want to have "admin" and  "client" portion in url I want to access both apps by just http://www.example.com:8100/ Is there any way to do that?

Is there any way that i can do it by using sub domain?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this using a single Tomcat instance.  The context path determines the WAR which will be hit.  One workaround would be to create a third proxy endpoint, which in turn would call the two Tomcat instances.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen If i do two tomcat instance, Can i access files which are in admin web app using client?

Comment: If they are on the same physical server, then potentially yes, you can.

Comment: Regarding your edit "...do it by using sub domain?" yes you can. Having a single apache tomcat instance you can configura a [virtual host](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html) for `admin.example.com` and deploy the `admin` app to its root, then configure a virtual host `client.example.com` and deploy the `client` app to its root. They a then available thru http://admin.example.com and http://client.example.com

Comment: @Selaron Can you provide me a tutorial link for that?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat instance will not be able to distinguish between "admin" and "client" portions if you do not have separate URLs for each of them. Hence not possible with a single Tomcat instance.

Comment: Can i access files which are in admin web app using client? If i do multiple tomcat instance

Comment: Yes you can do this.